# embeds many nested form, mongoid

Tags: document, mongoid

I am using mongoid as my database.

And my model is like this

```
class Address
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :person, :inverse_of => :addresses
end

class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :addresses
end
```

I am having problem in setting up dynamic nested person form where the user can add many addresses inside a form and save all of them at once.
My hash while updating the person nested form is like this

```
"person"=>{"name"=>"John", 
"addresses_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"address1"=>"calgary","address2"=>"New York", "id"=>"4cef79f67adf3509280001be"}, 
                         "1"=>{"address1"=>"bhah", "address2"=>"blah", "id"=>"4cef74rdeadf3509280001bf"}}, 
"policy_id"=>"4cef5feb7adf35092800013a", 
"start_date"=>"2010-11-10", "end_date"=>""}
```

But the address doesn't get updated according the hash recieved.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: You might get better answers if you retag this with ruby and mongo.  Also, you should get rid of the embedded tag, since it is not appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding accepted_nested_attributes_for to your Person model

Comment: ya i have added it. but i didn't mentioned in the question. Sorry.